# can't get custom field on Magento 1.6 store registration page into mysql database.?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have created a new field call childname which is a requierd field on an account registration form.

I have:

Added the form into the register.phtml ok and it displays on the form.

put this code into  /local/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml

```
              <childname>
                <create>1</create>
                <update>1</update>
              </childname>
```

Added this to /local/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Setup.php

```
                    'childname'         => array( 
            'type'               => 'varchar',                     
                    'label'              => 'Please Enter Childs Name',
                    'input'              => 'text',
                    'required'           => true,
                    'visible'            => true,
```

I have added the attribute_code childname set to varchar in eav_attribute table

I've run the reg page and looked in customer_entity_varchar but it is not being stored ?

Am I missing some code somewhere , not sure which file sends the data to the db ??

Any help would be appreciated !!

Thanks in advance

running Magento 1.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing I think that's missing is that you need to tell magento that this attribute is used in the forms, so that it will be processed. Basically, you'll want to include it in a variety of forms, as 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register', 'adminhtml_customer'.
So you need to put in an upgrade "sql file" something like:

```
$usedInForms = array('customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register', 'adminhtml_customer');
$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'childname');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', $usedInForms);
$oAttribute->save();
```

So, I've just made it myself for a client of mine, and it's actaully quite simple. You just need 3 files in your module and editing a couple of phtml.

1. etc/config.xml, as always in Magento, you need to configure your module. In our case, we just have to configure the resources. here is my whole config.xml:

   ```
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Osdave_Custattr>
               <version>0.1.0</version>
           </Osdave_Custattr>
       </modules>

       <global>
           <resources>
               <custattr_setup>
                   <setup>
                       <module>Osdave_Custattr</module>
                       <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                   </setup>
                   <connection>
                       <use>core_setup</use>
                   </connection>
               </custattr_setup>
               <custattr_write>
                   <connection>
                       <use>core_write</use>
                   </connection>
               </custattr_write>
               <custattr_read>
                   <connection>
                       <use>core_read</use>
                   </connection>
               </custattr_read>
           </resources>
       </global>
   </config>
   ```
2. sql/custattr_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php, this is the file which adds the attribute into the eav attributes tables. As you can see in the config.xml, it extends `Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup`. Again, the whole file:

   ```
   <?php

   $installer = $this;

   $installer->startSetup();

   $this->addAttribute('customer', 'erp_customer_id', array(
       'type' => 'varchar',
       'input' => 'text',
       'label' => 'ERP Customer ID',
       'global' => 1,
       'visible' => 1,
       'required' => 0,
       'user_defined' => 1,
       'default' => null,
       'visible_on_front' => 1
   ));


   if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.6.0', '<=')) {
       $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
       $attrSetId = $customer->getResource()->getEntityType()->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
       $this->addAttributeToSet('customer', $attrSetId, 'General', 'erp_customer_id');
   }

   if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.4.2', '>=')) {
       Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
               ->getAttribute('customer', 'erp_customer_id')
               ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register'))
               ->save();
   }

   $installer->endSetup();
   ```
3. the activation xml file, app/etc/modules/Osdave_Custattr.xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Osdave_Custattr>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>local</codePool>
           </Osdave_Custattr>
       </modules>
   </config>
   ```
4. and now I just have to edit the phtml files where I want the new field to show up, ie, registering, editing and checkout registering. Here is what I've add in my app/design/frontend/mypackage/mydesign/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml:

   ```
   <div class="fieldset">
       <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('ERP Account Information') ?></h2>
       <ul class="form-list">
           <li>
               <label for="erp_customer_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('ERP Customer ID') ?></label>
               <div class="input-box">
                   <input type="text" name="erp_customer_id" id="erp_customer_id" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getErpCustomerId()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('ERP Customer ID') ?>" class="input-text" />
               </div>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   ```

   it's important that the name of the field matches the name of the attribute.

Y voilá, when I register the field is stocked in the db.
Go through this, probably the best solution for you would be to get back the db-and-files backup you made before you start editing, and reproduce my steps. You'll have to change the name to match yours.

HTH

Comment: @OSDdave Many thanks, wheres the bests place to put this code ?

Comment: @Ledgemonkey the best place is app/code/local-or-community/YourNamespace/YourModule/sql/yourmodule_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php asuming that your module currently has version 0.1.0 and your first setup inserted a row into core_resource. but I'm not totally sure, as you give little info about your whole module.

Comment: again many thanks for your help, I'm using Local/Mage/Customer -  sql/customer_setup mysql4-upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.1.0.php  Should i create a new module in Local ?

Comment: well, in theory you can't do anything in Magento without creating a mouule, so yes, you definitely should create a module.

Comment: Made module , followed at least 6 tutorials edited, changed, reload got totally confused each tutorial says something different , don't know what to do now ? nothing gets sent to the database from the form ? any ideas ?

Comment: @Ledgemonkey tomorrow I'll have to create a customer attribute on a 1.6, I'll review the whole process and keep you posted.

Comment: thanks for your help on this, much appreciated, will give it a go and post back

Comment: i'm going to accept this answer , as its the clearest explanation I've had - its not the answers fault if I get it wrong ! thanks